# How to bind Gridview by column index instead of by column ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Normally binding data to gridview column is like this:

```
Text='<%# Bind("regionName") %>'
```

How do I bind by index instead?  For example:

```
Text='<%# Bind(1) %>'
```

The reason is because I am using a 2D list for datasource, and 2D list don't have column names.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following for `List<string[]>` and it worked inside repeater, not sure about gridview:

```
Text='<%# Eval("[1]")%>'
```